# How can i use a const of Vue methods inside a Vue template to show the const result?

Tags: vue.js

I have this alert component and in the body field im trying to use the const "item". The const "item" is in the Vue methods, is it possible to have the const "item" result in that alert body field? I tried {item} {{item}} without success. Thanks

```
<alert
        v-if="warning"
        :show-alert="showAlert"
        :options="{
          body: "message" {item} {{item}}
        }"
        color="#ffc107"
        style="max-width: 670px; width: 100%;"
        @input="showAlert = false"
      />
...


export default {
  data () {
return {
  warning: '',
  showAlert: true,
  item: null
}


},

...

methods: {
const item = result.hits[0].refs.id[0]

...
```

Comment: What is `result` in your methods? Is that an ajax response, a parameter passed in, etc.?

Comment: Yes exactly that.

Comment: Which of listed options does "yes" apply to? The question doesn't make sense without details.  `methods: {
const item` - this syntax is invalid. Please, check https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking. You cannot use `item` variable anywhere but the scope where it's defined, these are the basics of JS that aren't specific to Vue. If you want to access `item` in a template, you need to assign a value to `this.item`. If this happen to solve the problem, that's it

Comment: Thanks, already read those links before, but for a beginner is not easy to make question without some mistakes due to my lack of knowledge yet in Vue, but im learning. Yes applies to ajax response. I will try this.item, thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to have the const "item" result in that alert body field?

My Answer is No, Why you want to bind constant in your HTML template ? As you already have item property in your data object. You can update the item value in that property instead of assigning that in `const`.

**For Ex :** `this.item = 'item value'` instead of `const item = 'item value'`